Creating a dynamic zscore in powerBI using count as aggregate
I am trying to create a couple measures that will dynamically adjust a z-score value based on a count of entries in the the table that match both the month/year and the exception code.
Effectively what I have in the table looks like this:



Date (Date format: mmm yy)
Exception Code (text)
Job Name (text)
New / Old (text)




Jan 24
A
Alex
New


Jan 24
A
Bob
New


Jan 24
B
Carl
Old


Feb 24
A
Dan
Old


Feb 24
B
Eddie
New


Feb 24
B
Frank
New


Feb 24
B
Gary
New


Mar 24
A
Harold
Old


Mar 24
A
Ike
New


Mar 24
A
Jacob
Old


Mar 24
A
Kimbo
Old


Mar 24
A
Larry
Old


Mar 24
A
Mike
New


Mar 24
A
Nate
New


Mar 24
B
Oscar
Old


Mar 24
B
Pete
New



What I'm trying to get is roughly an output like this with nothing selected in the visual:



Date
Exception Code
Count
Mean
StdDev
ZScore




Jan 24
A
2
3.3333
2.6247
-0.51


Feb 24
A
1
3.3333
2.6247
-0.89


Mar 24
A
7
3.3333
2.6247
1.40


Jan 24
B
1
2.0000
0.6667
-2.00


Feb 24
B
3
2.0000
0.6667
1.50


Mar 24
B
2
2.0000
0.6667
0.00



And the reason I need it to function dynamically is so the table would look like this if a slicer was making it only show 'NEW' jobs for instance:



Date
Exception Code
Count
Mean
StdDev
ZScore




Jan 24
A
2
1.6667
1.2472
0.27


Feb 24
A
0
1.6667
1.2472
-1.34


Mar 24
A
3
1.6667
1.2472
1.07


Jan 24
B
0
1.3333
1.2472
-1.07


Feb 24
B
3
1.3333
1.2472
1.34


Mar 24
B
1
1.3333
1.2472
-0.27



I know there should be some combination of measures using allselected() and maybe summarize() with averagex() and stdevx.p() or something but for the life of me I'm unable to figure this out.  Any help would be phenomenal.  Please let me know if there's any information missing as well and I'll update.

How are you counting the Mean ? same for the StdDev and ZScore.

That's essentially what I'm asking for help with.  The mean of 3.3333 in Table2 for Exception Code 'A' is found from the counts of exception code A through all three months (2/1/7) added together (10) then divided by the number of months (3).  That's obviously how it's done mathematically, but getting powerbi to do that correctly is the issue that I need help with.  Unless I'm not understanding what you're asking?

I amanged to have the Count and the Mean, for StdDev and Zscore you may need to clarify the formula so I can continue working on it :
Create a CC for the count :
Count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(MyTable[Job Name (text)]),
    ALLEXCEPT(MyTable, MyTable[Date (Date format: mmm yy)], MyTable[Exception Code (text)])
)


Then I created a CT :
SummaryTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    MyTable,
    MyTable[FormattedDate],
    MyTable[Exception Code (text)],
    "Count", COUNT(MyTable[Job Name (text)])
)

Where I added another CC :
Mean = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(SummaryTable[Count]),
    ALLEXCEPT(SummaryTable, SummaryTable[Exception Code (text)])
)


